Installing Ubuntu Server 24.04 from an iDRAC virtual CD is stuck at "Block probing did not discover any disks"
I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server 24.04 on a Dell machine remotely using iDRAC, and the installation is stuck at Block probing did not discover any disks
I've read the fixes proposed in these questions:
Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 setup stuck at "Block probing did not discover any disks" Dell Optiplex 5080
Ubuntu Server 20.04 setup stuck at "Block probing did not discover any disks"
If I pull up a shell at the start of the installer things look like the attached screenshot:

The virtual CD is mounted at /cdrom and there are loop devices set up that point to the cdrom mount.
None of the suggested fixed of unmounting the mounted media (in this case /cdrom) work.
I've also done a quick check of the SATA settings and the embedded SATA is set to AHCI mode.

The issue here was that the raid array had not been configured. Running lsblk showed that the installer wasn't seeing any block devices with type disk. Configuring the RAID prior to the install fixed this.
From the iDRAC you need to boot into "Lifecycle Controller" and then select "Configure RAID and install OS"
